# Find Unique Sets in an ArrayList of Sets in Java

Tags: java

I have an ArrayList of Sets , I would like to find the unique sets among this ArrayList of Sets .

Please help me regarding this.

Comment: What have you tri...oh, never mind :)  How do you determine the uniqueness of the sets? Do they each have a unique number of items or do you consider two sets to be equal if they contain the exact same objects?

Comment: Your question is a little ill-defined, as I realised when I read @aix's answer. Do you mean you want all the unique sets, as in, each set that appears in the ArrayList, without duplicates? aix's answer works for this. Or do you want every Set that only appears once? Just checking, since I feel that if I can get confused over your meaning, other potential answers might not be what you're after.

Answer (score 5):

Let's call your `ArrayList<Set<T>>` `al`. You can put its elements into a `Set`:

```
Set<Set<T>> unique = new HashSet<Set<T>>(al);
```

The elements of `unique` will give you the unique sets.

P.S. In the above, `T` is some type (you haven't told us what it is, so I've used a generic name).

Comment: That will give him exactly one distinct copy of every set in his list, in other words, it will de-dupe his list. I think he wants only the sets that are already unique, discarding all instances of sets that have duplicates.

Comment: @Paul: Until you mentioned it, your interpretation of the question hasn't occurred to me. I'll wait for the OP to clarify their question.